# Is $x^6 + bx^3 + b^2$ irreducible?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, rational-numbers

Let $b\in \mathbb{Q}^*$ be rational number. We factorise $x^9-b^3\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and obtain $$x^9-b^3=(x^3-b)(x^6+bx^3+b^2).$$

Is the polynomial $x^6+bx^3+b^2$ irreducible?

If $b=1$ we get a cyclotomic polynomial, so yes. The same holds when $b$ is a cube. Is it true in general? It seems true because the roots of the polynomials are the $9$-th cube roots of $b^3$ and it seems that we cannot "separate" them, but is it true?

Comment: $$x^6+bx^3+b^2=(x^3-be^{\frac{2\pi}3i})(x^3-be^{-\frac{2\pi}3i})$$

Comment: The question was to be irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is given by Theorem $3.1$ [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjv7rvNu8iBAxWD2AIHHRGKAooQFnoECBQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mscand.dk%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F25850%2F23104&usg=AOvVaw0IS4Pgbc2EOadJf9_w3mnP&opi=89978449):

**Theorem 3.1.** Let $h(x)=x^2+bx+c\in \Bbb Z[x]$ be irreducible. Then
$$
f(x):=h(x^3)=x^6+bx^3+c
$$
is reducible if and only if $c=n^3$ and $b=m^3-3mn$ for some integers $m,n$.

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am probably missing something, but $b$ is assumed rational and not necessarily an integer, so the theorem does not seem to apply. Does the proof still go through if we multiply by the denominator of $b$? Additionally, it seems like the implication is that when $c=b^2$, those two equations have no solution - but I don't see why. The OP seems happy with it, so I guess I am missing something simple.

Comment: @preferred_anon Let us first assume $b\in \Bbb Z$. Then we have $(1) \; b^2=n^3$ and $(2) \; b=m^3-3mn$. So $m\mid b$ by $(2)$. Also conversely $b\mid m$: Let $p\mid b$ be a prime divisor of $b$. Then $p\mid n$, so $p\mid m^3$ by $(2)$ and hence $p\mid m$. Hence $m=\pm b$, and $(2)$ gives, say, $b=b^3-3bn$, so $1=b^2-3n=n^3-3n$.

Comment: we can always make a change of variables $x \mapsto x a$ and thus replace $b$ with $bc^3$ for each non zero integer $c$. So it is enough to consider the case where $b$ is an integer.

Comment: The paper is [The irreducibility of power compositional sextic polynomials and their Galois groups](https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-25850).

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to factor it over $\mathbb{C}$, and then see that no product of those factors is a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\omega$ be a primitive ninth root of unity, and let $\beta$ be the unique real cube root of $b$. Then,

$$p(x) = x^6+bx^3+b^2 = (x-\beta \omega)(x-\beta \omega^2)(x-\beta \omega^4)(x-\beta \omega^5)(x-\beta \omega^7)(x-\beta \omega^8)$$

Now note that if $p$ is reducible, one of the factors has degree $\le 3$. Clearly the degree is not $1$. If it is $2$, then we have a product which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$,

$$(x-\omega^n\beta)(x-\omega^m \beta) = x^2 - (\omega^n + \omega^m)\beta x + \omega^{m+n}\beta^2$$

but for the constant coefficient to even be real, we have to have $m$ congruent to $-n$ mod 9 - then $\beta(\omega^n + \omega^{-n}) = 2\beta \cos(2n\pi/9)$, which is not rational unless $\cos(2n\pi/9)$ is, i.e. unless $n$ is a multiple of 3.

So we are factoring into two degree 3 polynomials, but considering the constant coefficient of one of those polynomials, it is of the form $\omega^{m+n+k}b$: again, in order to be real, we have to have $m+n+k$ equal to 0 mod 9. the only way that can happen is if they are all 1 or all 2 mod 3. But then the $x^2$ coefficient has a factor of $\omega(1+\omega^3+\omega^6) = -\omega$ (or $-\omega^2$) which also isn't real.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It is good too.